# Allow admin access to sub_foldier in s3 bucket. Keep all other folders public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, amazon-iam

Lets say I have the following s3 structure

```
company_folder
  folder1
  folder2
  folder3
    sub_folder1 
    sub_folder2
```

I currently have the following permissions that allow access to every folder, sub_folder and file.  This is for a web app.

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "*"
},
"Action": "s3:GetObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company_folder/*"
```

Using an admin IAM access key id: ABCD I am able to put images into sub_folders using  carrierwave.  I use a single cloudfront root url to deliver images from various 'folders' and 'sub_folders'

The images sent to 'sub_folder2' are not displayed on the website and they are high resolution.  They should not be accessed by anyone except admin.

How do I go about changing the restrictions on 'sub_folder2' within the bucket policy for 'company_folder'

I need to deny GET and PUT access to 'sub_folder2' for everyone except admin while maintaining a public read on everything else in 'company_folder'.

I believe that the 'company_folder' needs to remain public because that is where my cloudfront url points to.

Is this a simple solution of just editing the bucket policy?

Comment: Might be easier to set up a different bucket for the more sensitive data

Comment: I think I need to keep it under the same bucket because I push other images to the company_folder with carrierwave.  Not sure I can point to two buckets in a single carrierwave initializer config.asset_host = ENV['HOST_NAME']
  config.fog_directory = ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following bucket policy should work for you.  The trick is to explicitly deny access to the resources/actions you don't want and then allow access to the ones you want.  Be careful with the interaction between bucket policies, IAM policies and object ACLs. Also make sure you make use of Trusted Advisor to warn you of buckets that are world readable.

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1429934459265",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1429934187436",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company_folder/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1429934452272",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:RestoreObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company_folder/folder3/sub_folder2/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::888888888888:user/youruser"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1429934245711",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::company_folder/folder3/sub_folder2/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i still cant perform GET requst on the private folder even though the allowed user is given access